# How to predict when next event occurs based on previous events?

Tags: statistics, prediction

Basically, I have a reasonably large list (a year's worth of data) of times that a single discrete event occurred (for my current project, a list of times that someone printed something). Based on this list, I would like to construct a statistical model of some sort that will predict the most likely time for the next event (the next print job) given all of the previous event times.

I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758036/predict-next-event-occurrence-based-on-past-occurrences), but the responses don't exactly help out with what I have in mind for my project. I did some additional research and found that a [Hidden Markov Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model) would likely allow me to do so accurately, but I can't find a link on how to generate a Hidden Markov Model using just a list of times. I also found that using a [Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) on the list may be useful but basically, I'd like to get some more information about it from someone who's actually used them and knows their limitations and requirements before just trying something and hoping it works.

Thanks a bunch!

**EDIT**: So by Amit's suggestion in the comments, I also posted this to the [Statistics StackExchange, CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16302/how-to-predict-when-the-next-event-occurs-based-on-times-of-previous-events). If you do know what I should do, please post either here or there

Comment: Maybe you could generate a list of 0s and 1s, putting ones where the events occur, zeros otherwise, then train a neural net to recognize the pattern. Basically if your list is 1000 events long, and you want to predict the next 100, then use a 1000->100 neural net.

Comment: You will probably get better answers in [statistics stackexchange](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Didn't know about that! I guess I should just repost this over there?

Comment: i really want to try the neural net / deep learning approach - seems illogically simple when stated that way (pattern of 1s and 0s).  thanks for posting that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll admit it, I'm not a statistics kind of guy. But I've run into these kind of problems before. Really what we're talking about here is that you have some observed, discrete events and you want to figure out how *likely* it is you'll see them occur at any given point in time. The issue you've got is that you want to take discrete data and make continuous data out of it.

The term that comes to mind is [density estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_estimation). Specifically [kernel density estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation). You can get some of the effects of kernel density estimation by simple binning (e.g. count the number events in a time interval such as every quarter hour or hour.) Kernel density estimation just has some nicer statistical properties than simple binning. (The produced data is often 'smoother'.)

That only takes care of one of your problems, though. The next problem is still the far more interesting one -- how do you take a time line of data (in this case, only printer data) and produced a prediction from it? First thing's first -- the way you've set up the problem may not be what you're looking for. While the miracle idea of having a limited source of data and predicting the next step of that source sounds attractive, it's far more practical to integrate more data sources to create an actual prediction. (e.g. maybe the printers get hit hard just after there's a lot of phone activity -- something that can be very hard to predict in some companies) The Netflix Challenge is a rather potent example of this point.

Of course, the problem with more data sources is that there's extra legwork to set up the systems that collect the data then.

Honestly, I'd consider this a domain-specific problem and take two approaches: Find time-independent patterns, and find time-dependent patterns.

An example time-dependent pattern would be that every week day at 4:30 Suzy prints out her end of the day report. This happens at specific times every day of the week. This kind of thing is easy to detect with fixed intervals. (Every day, every week day, every weekend day, every Tuesday, every 1st of the month, etc...) This is extremely simple to detect with predetermined intervals -- just create a curve of the estimated probability density function that's one week long and go back in time and average the curves (possibly a weighted average via a windowing function for better predictions).

If you want to get more sophisticated, find a way to automate the detection of such intervals. (Likely the data wouldn't be so overwhelming that you could just brute force this.)

An example time-independent pattern is that every time Mike in accounting prints out an invoice list sheet, he goes over to Johnathan who prints out a rather large batch of complete invoice reports a few hours later. This kind of thing is harder to detect because it's more free form. I recommend looking at various intervals of time (e.g. 30 seconds, 40 seconds, 50 seconds, 1 minute, 1.2 minutes, 1.5 minutes, 1.7 minutes, 2 minutes, 3 minutes, .... 1 hour, 2 hours, 3 hours, ....) and subsampling them via in a nice way (e.g. [Lanczos resampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_resampling)) to create a vector. Then use a [vector-quantization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_quantization) style algorithm to categorize the "interesting" patterns. You'll need to think carefully about how you'll deal with certainty of the categories, though -- if your a resulting category has very little data in it, it probably isn't reliable. (Some vector quantization algorithms are better at this than others.)

Then, to create a prediction as to the likelihood of printing something in the future, look up the most recent activity intervals (30 seconds, 40 seconds, 50 seconds, 1 minute, and all the other intervals) via vector quantization and weight the outcomes based on their certainty to create a weighted average of predictions.

You'll want to find a good way to measure certainty of the time-dependent and time-independent outputs to create a final estimate.

This sort of thing is typical of predictive data compression schemes. I recommend you take a look at [PAQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAQ) since it's got a lot of the concepts I've gone over here and can provide some very interesting insight. The source code is even available along with excellent documentation on the algorithms used.

You may want to take an entirely different approach from vector quantization and discretize the data and use something more like a [PPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_by_partial_matching) scheme. It can be very much simpler to implement and still effective.

I don't know what the time frame or scope of this project is, but this sort of thing can always be taken to the N-th degree. If it's got a deadline, I'd like to emphasize that you worry about getting something working first, and then make it work well. Something not optimal is better than nothing.

This kind of project is **cool**. This kind of project can get you a job if you wrap it up right. I'd recommend you do take your time, do it right, and post it up as function, open source, useful software. I highly recommend open source since you'll want to make a community that can contribute data source providers in more environments that you have access to, will to support, or time to support.

Best of luck!

Comment: i don't see this answer in the same post in that other stackexchange, but this answer is actually the most appropriate for the problem.  kernel density estimation will help you predict the interval to the next event, and provide the probability at any given time going forward.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't see how a Markov model would be useful here. Markov models are typically employed when the event you're predicting is dependent on previous events. The canonical example, of course, is text, where a good Markov model can do a surprisingly good job of guessing what the next character or word will be.

But is there a pattern to when a user might print the next thing? That is, do you see a regular pattern of time between jobs? If so, then a Markov model will work. If not, then the Markov model will be a random guess.

In how to model it, think of the different time periods between jobs as letters in an alphabet. In fact, you could assign each time period a letter, something like:

```
A - 1 to 2 minutes
B - 2 to 5 minutes
C - 5 to 10 minutes
etc.
```

Then, go through the data and assign a letter to each time period between print jobs. When you're done, you have a text representation of your data, and that you can run through any of the Markov examples that do text prediction.

Comment: The main assumption of the model is that there _should be_ a pattern in the timing print jobs.

Is there some way that you know of to generate the parameters for a Markov model from simply a list of times?

Comment: Why did you get upvote and not me? Title a markov model be a random guess is very vague and ambigous.

Comment: @Unk: I showed in my response how to create a Markov model from the list of times: convert the interval *between* the times to letters. The idea is that those intervals constitute a sort of alphabet--exactly the kind of thing you want for a Markov model. If you want to predict absolute times that print jobs are likely to run, your best bet is to forego the Markov model and just use some sort of clustering algorithm to compute the likelihood of a print job running at any particular time. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an actual model that you think might be relevant for the problem domain, you should apply it.  For example, it is likely that there are patterns related to day of week, time of day, and possibly date (holidays would presumably show lower usage).

Most raw statistical modelling techniques based on examining (say) time between adjacent events would have difficulty capturing these underlying influences.

I would build a statistical model for each of those known events (day of week, etc), and use that to predict future occurrences.

Comment: exactly.  what is important here is the time of each event, not the intervals between events.  you need to find what the useful ways of measuring that are (probably day of week and time of day) and then use the data to construct a probability distribution over those parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I think the predictive neural network would be a good approach for this task. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_analytics#Neural_networks

This method is also used for predicting f.x. weather forecasting, stock marked, sun spots. 
There's a tutorial here if you want to know more about how it works.
http://www.obitko.com/tutorials/neural-network-prediction/

Answer (score 0):

Think of a markov chain like a graph with vertex connect to each other with a weight or distance. Moving around this graph would eat up the sum of the weights or distance you travel. Here is an example with text generation: http://phpir.com/text-generation.

Answer (score 0):

A Kalman filter is used to track a state vector, generally with continuous (or at least discretized continuous) dynamics.  This is sort of the polar opposite of sporadic, discrete events, so unless you have an underlying model that includes this kind of state vector (and is either linear or almost linear), you probably don't want a Kalman filter.

It sounds like you don't have an underlying model, and are fishing around for one:  you've got a nail, and are going through the toolbox trying out files, screwdrivers, and tape measures 8^)

My best advice:  first, use what you know about the problem to build the model;  then figure out how to solve the problem, based on the model.